# Connecting to Mongo from Container

Tags: mongodb

I have mongod and docker running on a host.
Within the container I want to access mongod but I get,

```
root@bac0e41ed475:/opt/test# telnet 10.1.1.1 27017
Trying 10.1.1.1 ...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Am I missing something simple here ?

Comment: Show how you configured container's network. Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach ?

Comment: Changing the mongodb instances to listen on 0.0.0.0 and changed it to connect to the docker0 ip worked for me